Access token fetched from AWS Cognito oauth api endpoint is invalid when utilized by boto3
Having been confused by AWS Congito for weeks... Are there any difference between access tokens retrieved by /oauth2/token and boto3? If so, how can my backend use an access token passed from my frontend? Is it the only way that importing aws-sdk and aws-amplify?
Or I have to change all my workflow?

My frontend initiate the authorization flow via the Cognito hosted UI and get the access token(lets call it oauth access token) by exchanging the authorization code, then the access token is attached in header every time when my frontend requests my backend:
// If code is present, exchange it for a token
    const params = new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        code: code, /* the authorization code */
        redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
    });

    try {
        // Get token via aws api
        const response = await fetch(`${DOMAIN}/oauth2/token`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            body: params,
        });

My backend calls boto3.Session().client('cognito-idp').get_user() with the oauth access token sent by frontend, to get user information:
def _getUser(token:str): # here the access token passed from frontend lies
    # _cog_client is an instance of boto3.Session(...).client('cognito-idp')
    return {
        item["Name"]: item["Value"]
        for item in _cog_client.get_user(AccessToken=token)["UserAttributes"]
    }

and, EVERY SINGLE TIME the _getUser() raises NotAuthorizedException...

If the access token is retrieved by boto3.Session().client('cognito-idp').initiate_auth()(let's call it boto3 access token), get_user() won't raise error and it would function well:
def getAccessToken():
    # for test purpose
    resp=cog.initiate_auth(...) # cog is _cog_client, an instance of boto3.Session(...).client('cognito-idp')
    return resp["AuthenticationResult"]["AccessToken"]
_getUser(getAccessToken()) # this works well!


If I do not use get_user() but a GET call via, say, Requests, it would work:
import requests as rq
ret=rq.get(
    "https://<my cognito domain>/oauth2/userInfo",
    headers={
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}', # the oauth2 access token, NOT the boto3 access token
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
print(ret.json()) # 200 OK and expected response


So back to my question, are they really different and cannot be used in the other way(which means I would have to change either of my work flow), or my work flow itself is not good practice, i.e. the access token shouldn't be fetched and pass(really?)?

Can't help directly but OAuth is a nightmare so I reccomend switching to using withAuthenticator on your front end export instead. Here is an example where I used the amplify cli to install an auth and then call the logged in user's email.
I switched to this method after getting absolutely stuck from trying to post the auth token from the query params, the step before you are on.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import cognito_config from '../amplifyconfiguration.json'
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { getCurrentUser , fetchUserAttributes } from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import { withAuthenticator} from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
Amplify.configure(cognito_config);

function Dashboard() {
  const [spouseEmail, setSpouseEmail] = useState('');
  const [argumentTopic, setArgumentTopic] = useState('');
  const [initiated, setInitiated] = useState(false);
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState('');

  


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserEmail = async () => {
      try {
        const userAttributes = await fetchUserAttributes();
          if (userAttributes.email) {
            console.log("Pulled email" , userAttributes.email)
            setUserEmail(userAttributes.email);
            console.log("userEmail var:", userEmail);
          } else {
              console.log("Error: User email not found in attributes");
            }
         
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error fetching user data:", err);
      }
    };

    fetchUserEmail();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("userEmail state updated:", userEmail);
  }, [userEmail]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Start a discussion</h1>
      {!initiated ? (
        <>
          <input type="email" value={spouseEmail} onChange={(e) => setSpouseEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Spouse's Email" />
          <input type="text" value={argumentTopic} onChange={(e) => setArgumentTopic(e.target.value)} placeholder="Argument Topic" />
          <button onClick={handleInitiate}>Initiate Argument</button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <p>Argument initiated. Waiting for spouse to join.</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(Dashboard);


Thank you for your reply! So I still have to import Amplify right?

Yes amplify init and then amplify add auth I think. It does all confugration through the cli so go through it slowly after hitting enter.  Even with this method I still couldn't get Google oAuth to work with its credential key but just plan email and/or username with password worked.
Just export every component wrapped in withAutnehticator.
